# Override layout.subviews deletion control in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement similar code to this in a Swift project

https://gist.github.com/joaofranca/3159618

I am having difficulty getting the class for the subview in the NSStringFromClass sections.

I have tried NSStringFromClass(subview.class) but Swift doesn't like it.

Do you know how to use this in Swift?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

You can call `classForCoder` on classes derived from `NSObject`:

```
var s: NSObject = "hello"
var i: NSObject = 3
NSStringFromClass(s.classForCoder)    // "NSString"
NSStringFromClass(i.classForCoder)    // "NSNumber"
```

---

**Original answer:**

In Swift, instead of identifying a class by name, use `is`:

**Objective-C:**

```
for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {

    if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) { 

        // do magic here 
        ...

    }else if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {

        // do magic here
        ...

    }else if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"]) {

        // do magic here
```

**Swift:**

```
for subview in self.subviews as [UIView] {

    if subview is UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl { 

        // do magic here 
        ...

    } else if subview is UITableViewCellEditControl {

        // do magic here
        ...

    } else if subview is UITableViewCellReorderControl {

        // do magic here
```

Comment: there is no definition for UITableViewCellEditControl what to include to add it

Comment: there is no UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl in swift. It is showing unresolved identifier. How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 2.0** ->
Override the layoutSubviews()

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

override func aSubView() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    for aSubView in self.subviews {
        if String(aSubView.classForCoder).rangeOfString("UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView") != nil {
            // Do whatever you want to do with default Delete Button.
            // aSubView is the Delete Button.
            aSubView.frame = CGRectMake(aSubView.frame.origin.x, aSubView.frame.origin.y, aSubView.frame.size.width, aSubView.frame.size.height - 10)
        }
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer several times. If the question is a duplicate, flag it as duplicate; otherwise, tailor your answer to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

swift 3.0 -> using constraints.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    for aSubView in self.subviews as [UIView] {
        if String(describing: aSubView.classForCoder).range(of: "UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView") != nil {
            aSubView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                aSubView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
                aSubView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            ])
        }
    }
}
```